# Unexplainable WCF Service Timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, iis-7, wcf-binding, wcf-client

Running an MVC web site that calls a WCF service.
Site and service on 2 different machines.
.NET framework 4; IIS 7.

Production site is encountering a timeout when it should not.  I created the simplest samples I could (simple web site that calls service method that returns "hi mom" after a delay) and was able to reproduce the problem.  Here is how it goes:

- Client web app has it's binding's SendTimeout set to 6 minutes.
- Server service does nothing but write a message to a file, sleep for 5 minutes, write another message.
- Messages written to file on server are correct; server trace shows no problems.
- Client never receives return value from server service method.  It's like it just loses it's connection to the server.
- Client throws TimeoutException after 6 minutes (any timeout greater than that just delays the exception further).
  If I change the thread sleep time on the server to 4 minutes, everything works fine.  This is repeatable, and there is nobody else messing with this test scenario.

So here is the pertinent config section of the client:

```
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
             closeTimeout="00:6:00"
             openTimeout="00:6:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:6:00"
             sendTimeout="00:6:00"
             allowCookies="false"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             messageEncoding="Text"
             textEncoding="utf-8"
             transferMode="Buffered"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true">

<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200"
             maxRequestLength="10240" />

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="00:6:00" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

The same values are present on the server.
Following include things I've tried:

- Added the serviceTimeouts element above.
- Ensured to call close on the client proxy class (even though that wouldn't be the issue in my case since the error happens every time).
- Created a channel explicitly, cast as IContextChannel and set OperationTimeout (as outlined [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCF_Operation_Timeout_.aspx)).
- Increased the FailureInterval property of the server's app pool in IIS.
- Ensured that all the timeout values of the binding element in the configs were all set to a value greater than the time taken by the service method.
- Created a ChannelFactory and set it's Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout value.
- Ensured that Compilation debug="false" was set at client and server (read that timeouts [unsure which timeouts] not respected correctly unless this is set).
- Increased maxBufferSize, maxBufferPoolSize, and maxReceivedMessageSize even though this shouldn't have anything to do with the problem (the server simply returns "hi mom").
- Set SendTimeout explicitly in code on the client proxy (since this should be the relevant timeout).
- Called the service from a console app (same result).

What else can I try?

[Edit]
Moved the service to the same machine as the web app and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was HTTP policy on firewall in production environment: max request time 5 minutes.